# When does $\mu_n(C)\to \mu(C)$ for closed $C$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

For bounded variation Radon measures on $X$, s.t.
$$\lim \int_X f \text d \mu_n =\int_X f \text d \mu$$
for all $f\in C_0(X)$ i.e. $\mu_n$ converges vaguely to $\mu$, which closed sets satisfy
$$\lim_n \mu_n(C)=\mu(C)?$$
If $\mu_n$ are positive measures and $\lim_n \mu_n(X)=\mu(X)$ then our vague convergence improves to weak convergence of measures (i.e. we can replace $C_0(X)$ with $C_b(X)$) and the Portmanteau Theorem gives us that
$$\lim_n\mu_n(A)=\mu(A)$$
precisely when $\mu(\partial A)=0$.

However, the sequence $\mu_n=\delta_{-1/n}-\delta_{1/n}$ breaks only the positivity assumption and already the conclusions fail. Similarly, restricting $f\in C_0(X)$ and taking now $\mu_n=\delta_n$ so that $\mu \equiv 0$ shows that we are again empty handed if we ignore the limit condition.

All of these obstacles arise even without considering complex measures. What can we say in general about the setwise behavior of measures that converge in the above sense?

Comment: The classical criterion for this is $\mu(\partial C) = 0$.  Approximate the interior by continuous functions from below, and the closure by continuous functions from above.